# What are the conditions for snakemake to execute a job?

Tags: snakemake

I would like to know all necessary criteria required for snakemake to decide that a job needs to be executed, but I couldn't find them in [their documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io). The best source I have found is in snakemake author's [slides from 2016](https://slides.com/johanneskoester/snakemake-tutorial-2016#/23), which says:

```
A job is executed if and only if

- output file is target and does not exist
- output file needed by another executed job and does not exist
- input file newer than output file
- input file will be updated by other job
- execution is enforced
```

However it appears he has stopped using that slide since then, which makes me wonder if above criteria have changed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page of their documentation has a link to the slides from 2019: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html. On the page 26 of the slides you may see the same set of rules: https://slides.com/johanneskoester/snakemake-tutorial#/25:

```
Job execution
A job is executed if and only if

- output file is target and does not exist
- output file needed by another executed job and does not exist
- input file newer than output file
- input file will be updated by other job
- execution is enforced

determined via breadth-first-search on DAG of jobs
```

I guess that nothing has changed in these rules since 2019, especially taking in the consideration that this presentation is referenced from the official tutorial page.

Comment: Good find. Somehow I missed those slides. Thanks!
PS - Strange that these are not defined in documentation. I'll file an issue.