# What changes invalidate snakemake pipeline

Tags: workflow, pipeline, bioinformatics, snakemake, reproducible-research

It is not clear what changes will invalidate the pipeline and prompt snakemake to re-run the workflow.

Does change in input, intermediate output or custom script re-run the pipeline? In my experience changing intermediate output and custom script does not invalidate the pipeline and having that feature may improve reproducibility.

Comment: [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62419042/3998252) here would partly answer this question.

Comment: Thanks! @ManavalanGajapathy have you filed an issue?

Comment: @timing, it is clearly defined behavior.. You can update the timestamps of all your outputs with `--forceall --touch`.

Comment: @timing [Yes](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/449)

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande thanks! some tools like targets-r-package support monitoring of scripts and inputs so i was expecting that from snakemake too...